# How to configure CXF in TomEE

Tags: java, rest, cxf, apache-tomee

Is it possible to override settings in TomEE for the embedded CXF JaxRS container? I've been trying to integrate my own in-interceptor for handling rouing of JaxRS services.

What I can't seem to do is get TomEE to load the interceptor when starting my service.

I've read a bunch of stuff that says that I should be able to configure the CXF stuff in TomEE by adding <pojo-deployment> to an openejb-jar.xml file in either META-INF or WEB-INF. When I try using this approach, my interceptor never gets called.

I've also seen references that state that TomEE uses tomee.xml to replace openejb-jar.xml, so I tried to do the pojo-deployment stuff there, but then I get an XML parse error because tomee.xml doesn't seem to understand the pojo-deployment tag.

Can someone point me to some decent docs or better yet a small example of configuring CXF in TomEE?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

openejb-jar.xml is the way to do it

I blogged about it here http://rmannibucau.wordpress.com/2012/10/04/jax-rsjax-ws-configuration-for-tomee-1-5-0/

only change on recent tomee version is the fact you need to set as class-name the jaxrs application you use (if noone use "jaxrs-application" which means default behavior)

so something like:

```
<openejb-jar xmlns="http://www.openejb.org/openejb-jar/1.1">
  <pojo-deployment class-name="jaxrs-application">
    <properties>
      cxf.jaxws.in-interceptors = org.superbiz.MyInInterceptor
    </properties>
  </pojo-deployment>
</openejb-jar>
```